# Laravel and Vue3 upgrade issues with the vue-template-compiler

Tags: laravel-8, vuejs3

I am trying to upgrade from Vue2 to Vue3 but getting errors.

I have installed vue3 latest version, installed @vue/compiler-sfc and tried to remove vue-template-compiler but when I do npm run dev keeps getting below error, I have gone through lots of SO posts but still getting this error.

Vue3 doesn't need vue-template-compiler but why I am still getting below error. Could anyone help please? Thanks!

```js
Module Error (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js):
[vue-loader] vue-template-compiler must be installed as a peer dependency, or a compatible compiler implementation must be passed via options.



Module build failed (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'parseComponent' of undefined
    at parse(...\node_modules\@vue\component-compiler-utils\dist\parse.js:15:23)
    at Object.module.exports(...\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\index.js:67:22)
```

My package.json file looks like this:

```json
 "devDependencies": {
        "@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.1.2",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "jquery": "^3.6",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.19",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "postcss": "^8.3.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
        "sass": "^1.32.13",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "ts-loader": "^9.2.2",
        "typescript": "^4.3.2",
        "vue": "^3.1.2",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.7",
        "webpack": "^5.39.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "5.*",
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.2",
        "vue-router": "^4.0.10"
    }
```

packages.json doesn't have vue-template-compiler. I have tried removing while node_modules folder and did npm install and npm run dev but these errors are still appearing.

Thanks

Comment: You also need to update `vue-loader` to version v16.1.2

Comment: you should also delete the `yarn.lock` file, maybe there are still fragments from the old version.

Comment: Thanks @wittgenstein it worked after I updated the vue-leader version and then removed package-lock.json as I was running my application on windows.

Comment: nice to hear that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone else facing this issue, I did below steps to solve this issue:

1. Upgraded `vue-loader` to version `v16.1.2`
2. Removed `node_modules` folder from the root directory
3. Removed `package-lock.json` from the root directory
4. Run `npm install`
5. npm run dev

Now files compiled successfully.
Hope its helpful.